# This statement returning Yii::$app->request->baseUrl empty

Tags: yii2

i am new you yii2 and i want to get baseUrl in yii2 for that i had written following statement but it return nothing

```
<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>
```

Comment: are you using the  yii2 basic template or advanced template

Comment: It seems your base url (relative) is just /, but without slash ) So it's just empty string )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to get Base url in Yii2 is:

```
Yii::$app->HomeUrl
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try with  :  `<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->baseUrl ?>`
Hope this will work.

Comment: this is url my http://mysite.in/index.php?r=stud/view&id=1 i want to get mysite.in but your code give me only "/index.php" as output i had already tried this one

Comment: even return blank

Comment: any parameter or code i have write to set baseurl ?

Comment: Add statement  in header of view file  : `use yii\helpers\Url;` and  `echo Url::home(true);`         or     `echo Url::home();` .